# Python 3.4 - how to get properties of an open window (size, position on screen e.t.c) and gui automation

Tags: python, automation, window

Python 3.4 . I want to get the properties of an open window (size, position on screen e.t.c) if possible. is there an easy way to do this?. Also is there a good module for simulating mouse clicks and key presses in an open application

Comment: Look at tkinter, a GUI development module that ships with python

Comment: I've used Sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/) to perform mouse clicks and key presses, but I think you'll have a hard time finding something that gives you a Python API to check window size. Also, Sikuli uses ``Jython``

Answer (score 0):

if you using *tkinter*, one of the most common GUI packet, then:

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry('400x600')

root.update()

print (root.winfo_width())
print (root.winfo_height())
print (root.winfo_x())
print (root.winfo_y())

root.mainloop()
```

you can replace:

```
print (root.winfo_width())
print (root.winfo_height())
print (root.winfo_x())
print (root.winfo_y())
```

with:

```
print (root.winfo_geometry())
```